# why is jquery not loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

for some reason when i try to load jquery via cdn, it works perfectly

```
script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"
```

however, when i try to load it using the local files, it does not work

```
script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"
```

and displays this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <                  jquery-1.11.2.min.js:1
```

i must say that my server is running on node.js

Comment: could you post the full tag declaration?

Answer (score 1):

it seems you have syntax error with your tag.

try this.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though there is an error occurring *inside* `jquery-1.11.2.min.js`. *Not* in the document which contains the `script` tag. So, the question is: why does your local copy of `jquery-1.11.2.min.js` contain a `<`? The answer is that it most likely doesn't. The request for `jquery-1.11.2.min.js` is probably resulting in a HTML response, which the browser attempts to load as JavaScript, and fails on the first character. Ensure that `javascripts/jquery-1.11.2.min.js` is the correct path to your JavaScript file.

It can be shown that this is the case because a [`SyntaxError`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SyntaxError) is a **JavaScript** error. MDN says the following (emphasis mine):

> A `SyntaxError` is thrown when the **JavaScript engine** encounters tokens or token order that does not conform to the syntax of the language when parsing code.

So, the error is being thrown by the JavaScript engine, which means that the browser is actually trying to load a script file. As you can see from the error message, the error is thrown at `jquery-1.11.2.min.js:1`, which is line one of `jquery-1.11.2.min.js`. You can **reproduce** the same error message using the following code saved in a file named `foo.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="foo.html"></script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

Alternatively, you can view a demonstration of equivalent code [here](http://jsbin.com/vuporiqefi/1/edit?html,output) (check your console).

Comment: Does anyone have an idea as to why I have been downvoted? I can improve my answer once I know _why_.

Comment: Just to summarise this happens sometimes when you have a 404 page, or a route which doesn't work so you are actually seeing the first character of a page similar to `<html><body>Error: unable to find page</body></html>`. Open the script you are linking to and see if the page works.

Comment: @Djave Thanks! Just as you have mentioned, I also suggested that it might be a 404 page, but I ended up editing it out because I didn't want to confuse anyone with my contradictions. If it's a true 404 (with the appropriate status code), Chrome will log "net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND" or "404 (Not Found)" '_without_ passing it to the JavaScript engine. So, it's most likely a 404 page without a 404 status code.